# How to fix: "No visible @interface for 'FIRInstanceID' declares the selector 'token'" in iOS build in Flutter

Tags: objective-c, firebase, flutter

The problem occurred when I tried to build the iOS version of my flutter app that uses Firebase Messaging after updating Firebase pod to 6.0.1. I never use Objecrtive C this is why this error is confusing

I can get it to work by just commenting out the line that causes the problem. I'm not sure how important it is to have this piece of code for production.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
#ifdef DEBUG
[[FIRMessaging messaging] setAPNSToken:deviceToken    type:FIRMessagingAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
#else
[[FIRMessaging messaging] setAPNSToken:deviceToken  type:FIRMessagingAPNSTokenTypeProd];
#endif
//[_channel invokeMethod:@"onLaunch" arguments:_launchNotification];
[_channel invokeMethod:@"onToken" arguments:[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]];
}
```

Expected result is just building the app but I get the error.

Comment: Hi Karol, did you resolve it? I have the same problem :(
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that the version of `firebase_messaging` package you've used is outdated. At the moment, the current version is [`firebase_messaging 7.0.3`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/versions). Based on the date that you've posted this question, I think you are using the [`firebase_messaging 5.0.1+1`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/versions/5.0.1+1).

Also, one of the [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mdanics/fluttergram/issues/57#issuecomment-542391012) have some workaround.

- As mentioned, instead of using the outdated version of firebase_messaging package. Use the latest version of it.
- `pod update` in ios folder of the project
- Run `flutter clean`

If this doesn't work, try to provide at least a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code that produces the issue and the result when you run `flutter doctor`.